# BeautifulSoup: get an element on a page AFTER specified text?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have an HTML page with the following table.

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="headerValueClass" colspan="2">First Group</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>First Person</td>
    <td>Angie Apple</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Second Person</td>
    <td>bobby Brown</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Third Person</td>
    <td>Cathy Connor</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="headerValueClass" colspan="2">Second Group</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>First Person</td>
    <td>Danny Dean</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Second Person</td>
    <td>Eli Edwards</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Third Person</td>
    <td>Frank Fring</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="headerValueClass" colspan="2">Third Group</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>First Person</td>
    <td>George Golf</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Second Person</td>
    <td>Henry Hightower</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Third Person</td>
    <td>Ingrid Idle</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I craft a BeautifulSoup expression to find the first, second, and third persons in each of the first, second, and third groups? For the first group, I can use:

```
theText = theSoup.find('td', text='First Person').findNext('td').text
```

But I now need an expression that basically says, "just like that expression above, but after the "Second Group" text."

Regrettably, the source page gives me very little else to go on.

Comment: I get the sense you may have abbreviated the table a bit much here -- why not use `soup.select("td:nth-child(2)")`? If the actual table is more complciated, I suggest editing your post to motivate why the direct solution won't work on your use case. If you have a live link to the page, that's best. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using beautifulsoup and CSS selectors:

```
groups = soup.select('tr:has(td.headerValueClass)') 
for g in groups:
    print(g.select_one('td').text)
    for ns in g.fetchNextSiblings()[:3]:
        print(ns.select_one('td:nth-child(2)').text)
    print('===================')
```

If available, I would prefer to use xpath with lxml:

```
import lxml.html as lh
players = """your html above"""
doc = lh.fromstring(players)

groups = doc.xpath('//tr[td[@class="headerValueClass"]]')
for g in groups:
    print(g.xpath('./td/text()')[0])
    for fs in g.xpath('./following-sibling::tr')[:3]:
        print(fs.xpath('.//td[2]/text()')[0])
    print('===================')
```

Output in either case:

```
First Group
Angie Apple
bobby Brown
Cathy Connor
===================
Second Group
Danny Dean
Eli Edwards
Frank Fring
===================
Third Group
George Golf
Henry Hightower
Ingrid Idle
===================
```